# Continued fraction of the square $\sqrt{n}$ of the form $[a,\overline{k,b}]$

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

Continued fraction of the square $\sqrt{n}$ for a fixed $k >2 $
can we say there are infinitely man $n$ such that $\sqrt{n} =$ $[a,\overline{k,b}]$?

If so would the proof go by the route of contradiction? Could one claim one is the largest and contradict it by finding a larger one?

Comment: Your title and the text of the question disagree.  The last item in the repeat is always twice the integer part, so has to be $2a$.  Do you mean to have another term in the repeat or not?

Comment: The continued fractions for numbers one more or less than a square have special forms that may match what you are asking about.

Comment: @RossMillikan sorry that would be the complete form as in b = 2a.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [expansions of the small square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Square_roots_of_positive_integers), it appears that if $k$ divides $2a$ the expansion of $a^2+\frac {2a}k$ is of the form $[a,\overline {k,2a}]$.  Go through the continued fraction expansion and see if this works.

Added:  given $k$ we can find infinitely many examples where the expansion is $[a,\overline{k,2a}]$.  Choose any $a$ so that $k$ divides $2a$.  Then $\sqrt{a^2+\frac {2a}k}=[a,\overline{k,2a}].$

The proof is just to compute it.
$$\sqrt{a^2+\frac {2a}k}=a+\sqrt{a^2+\frac {2a}k}-a\\
=a+\frac 1{\frac 1{\sqrt{a^2+\frac {2a}k}-a}}\\
=a+\frac 1{\frac {\sqrt{a^2+\frac {2a}k}+a}{(a^2+\frac {2a}k)-a^2}}\\
=a+\frac 1{\frac {\sqrt{a^2+\frac {2a}k}+a}{\frac {2a}k}}\\
=a+\frac 1{\frac k{2a}\left(\sqrt{a^2+\frac {2a}k}+a\right)}\\
=a+\frac 1{k+\frac k{2a}\left(\sqrt{a^2+\frac {2a}k}-a\right)}\\
=a+\frac 1{k+\frac 1{\frac {2a}{k\left(\sqrt{a^2+\frac {2a}k}-a\right)}}}\\
=a+\frac 1{k+\frac 1{\frac {2a\left(\sqrt{a^2+\frac {2a}k}+a\right)}{2a}}}\\
=a+\frac 1{k+\frac 1{2a-\left(\sqrt{a^2+\frac {2a}k}-a\right)}}$$
If you choose $a=\frac k2$ you will get an expansion $[a,\overline{2a,2a}]$ which is not the minimal one.  If that bothers you, prohibit that case.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re merely asking whether there are infinitely many $n$ for which the expansion of $\sqrt n$ is of that form, that’s easy, since the expansion of $\sqrt{n^2+2n}$ is $[n,\overline{1,2n}]$. Notice that $n^2-2n$ is just one less than a square.

Comment: I think OP wants a different $k$ than $1$

Comment: Ah, surenough, @RossMillikan .